# Does Arduino beta have a community ad?

Tags: support

I realize beta sites don't have ads *on* the site, but I'd like to put one *for* the site on rotation at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ (they are being renewed for the year now).

If not and someone wants to whip something up, please do -- leave a comment if you need a bit of time, otherwise tomorrow I will.  Technically, the ads can be replaced after posting although that may be limited by when it crosses the upvote threshold.

The meta thread on RPi.SE is here: https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/893/community-promotion-ads-2017 For those that aren't familiar with this, Stack Exchange does it annually for all graduated sites.  The ads appear in the side bar and have a target link (which would be Arduino.SE).

Comment: Where would it go? I went to the Pi site and didn't see any ads.

Comment: You're not the only one -- never something I've looked into.  Anyway, it's in the sidebar right  *above* "Hot Network Questions".

Comment: I had to disable Adblock, and various trackers to see it.

Comment: Yeah there's google driven ads in there; sometime last year they started doing it on selected sites for all users regardless of rep (I believe there's a top bar one everywhere for the new-ish).  We were so blessed because we have a lot of page views...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, I widened your graphic a bit:

[image: Widened graphic]

Comment: \O/ You should throw it up on EE now too, all the "Community Promotion" renewals are done at the same time: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6082/community-promotion-ads-2017

Answer (score 1):

I found one over on Electrical Engineering done last year by Camil Staps:

[image]

The new criteria require it be 300x250, though:

[image]

Comment: Yuk, it needs to be re-done. :)

Comment: @NickGammon Padding instead of stretching seems an improvement.

Comment: Yes but it looks a bit, er, bold. It should be possible to redo it easily enough.